# How can I multi-edit tasks to assign each to a different user story?

Tags: rally

In Rally, it takes a few clicks in the UI to re-parent a task. When many tasks have to be reparented it is impractical to do it one at a time. The drop down on "Multi-Edit: Task" page allows to change Name, State, Estimate, ToDo, and Owner but does not allow to change Work Product even when this column is added to a custom view on a Tasks summary page.

Comment: True it's not a full move, but you could "Actions => Copy Tasks from..." in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to bulk-reassign tasks to a different user story in the UI. Here is a Ruby code, using [Rally Ruby REST tookit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) 
that re-assign a group of tasks based on a tag to a different story.
It is using `stop_after` variable just to put some guardrails around the bulk edit.

```
require 'rally_api'

headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "bulk action: set workproduct on tasks"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"


config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "W"
config[:project] = "P1"
config[:headers] = headers

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :task
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,Description,WorkProduct"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111" } 
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/2222" } 
query.page_size = 200 #optional - default is 200
query.limit = 1000 #optional - default is 99999
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down = true
query.order = "Name Asc"
query.query_string = "(Tags.Name = tag1)"

story = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/33333" } 

tasks_results = @rally.find(query)
tasks = [];
stop_after = 10
count = 0

tasks_results.each do |t|
     count +=1
         break if count > stop_after
    puts "Name: #{t["Name"]}, FormattedID: #{t["FormattedID"]}"
    t.read
    tasks << t
end

tasks.each do |t|
    puts "acting on Name: #{t["Name"]}, FormattedID: #{t["FormattedID"]}"
    field_updates = {"WorkProduct" => story}
    t.update(field_updates)
end
```